# jquery not triggering on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, zurb-foundation

I'm starting to insert some amateur jQuery into my Django project, and I'm having some trouble. HTML HEAD section of the file looks like this:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>     
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}javascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').orbit();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('#edit').click(function () {
    alert("heyyyy")
    });
</script>
```

In the BODY I have a button with the ID="edit".

```
<button id="edit" class="small button right">Izmeni</button>
```

If I paste this code into jsFiddle it will work, I can see the alert. However, it does not work in my case. Only difference from jsFiddle is that I'm using Zurb foundation framework, which comes with lots of jQuery functions and they all work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach your event handler *after* the element is created within the DOM. The reason it works in a jsFiddle is because jsFiddle automatically wraps your code inside of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems logical, but since my dev server just went bananas I'll accept your answer blindly without trying it out :)

Answer (score 0):

To bind it, you can do something like

```
$(document).on('click','#edit',function() {
    alert('Hey');
});
```

replace `document` with your parent container.